# C# - Getting response from WebResponse

Tags: c#, html, xml, windows-10

I'm trying to download XML source code of RSS feed placed in the internet, but when my process reaches `WebResponse` statement (second line bellow) process stops and nothing next is happening. There si no error, no exception or nothing like that. I'm waiting for tens of minutes and still nothing happening.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(source.Url);
WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync(); // at this line it stops
Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);

string xml = readStream.ReadToEnd().Trim();

readStream.Dispose();
response.Dispose();
```

Any idea what causing it?

EDIT:

```
public static async Task<string> GetContent(string uri)
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

    using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
    {
        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);

        return readStream.ReadToEnd().Trim();
    }
}

public async Task<ObservableCollection<Source>> GetArticlesFromSource()
{
    sourceDefinitions = await GetSourceDefinitions();

    string imageFolderName = "ArticleImages";
    string imageFolderPath = localFolder.Path + "\\" + imageFolderName;
    StorageFolder imageFolder = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync(imageFolderName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

    foreach (var source in sourceDefinitions)
    {
        if (source.Selected == "true")
        {
            ObservableCollection<Article> articlesStep1 = new ObservableCollection<Article>();
            /*WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(source.Url);
            WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);*/

            string xml = await GetContent("http://www.honzachalupa.cz/").ConfigureAwait(false);

            Debug.WriteLine(xml);
            ...
```

Comment: Pertinent to you code, use: WebResponse response = request.GetResponse(). It should work. Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Your application is almost certainly calling `Wait` or `Result` on a returned task further up the call stack, and this [will cause a deadlock](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that I explain in full on my blog.

To fix it, find the upstream `Wait`/`Result` call and change it to `await`. In other words, use "async all the way".

Comment: I did it as you wrote on your blog, but still stopping on `var jsonString = await client.GetStringAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);` line. It's not continuing to `return`.

Comment: @JanChalupa: Did you change all `Wait` and `Result` instances to `await`? If so, please post a complete minimal repro.

Comment: I don't know exactly, what do you mean with `Wait` and `Result`. I edited my original post with more complex part of my code with changes according to your blog.

Comment: @JanChalupa: Please edit your code until it is a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then edit it into your answer. That way we can reproduce it and find out what the problem is instead of just guessing.